# How do you upgrade swift tools in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, coreml

I am attempting to run stable diffusion on core-ml but I get the error:

```
error: package at '/Documents/Diffusion/Apple_Diffuser/ml-stable-diffusion_swift' is using Swift tools version 5.7.0 but the installed version is 5.5.0
```

It seems like upgrading should be straight forward but nothing I try works. MacOS is up to date and so is Xcode. Apple has a downloads page for it but its from 2019 and tells me the operating system is too new. The swift website has no MacOS installer. This seems like a straight forward problem but I cannot figure it out. Nothing I try installs swift tools. I've tried installing "Command Line Tools" and "Additional Tools" and also tried to upgrade from the command line with Xcode and software update as well as the App Store.

Comment: stable diffusion with python and cormel works but it can only produce a single image so I am trying to use swift

Comment: What's the output of `xcrun swift -version` or `swift --version` in terminal?

Comment: Target: arm64-apple-macosx13

Comment: Is it not displaying your version of swift (e.g. `Apple Swift version 5.7 (swiftlang-5.7.0.127.4 clang-1400.0.29.50)`)?

Comment: Sorry. It is. It's showing swift-driver version: 1.26.21 Apple Swift version 5.5.2 (swiftlang-1300.0.47.5 clang-1300.0.29.30)

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can you confirm again that you're using Xcode 14 (Click Xcode > About in the toolbar)?

Comment: Version 14.2 (14C18)

Comment: Yeah, really weird. Might try either a fresh install of Xcode (since Swift 5.7 is default for 14.2) or following the installation instructions here on https://www.swift.org/download/ and set it via the Xcode toolchain. Other than, I'm not really sure 

Answer (score 0):

Installing swift for Xcode from https://www.swift.org/download/ didn't work. The solution was to drag Xcode to the trash and reinstall Xcode from the App Store. Reinstalling from the version of Xcode on the web did not work.